# how to detect whenever java project is successfully compiled in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I am making a plugin with intelliJ to test java project. I am wondering how to detect whenever the java project is successfully compiled by the user? maybe return a boolean or something?

can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the toolbar click in **Build** Option, then click the **Rebuild option** latter a dialog named *Message Make* show the result